# ImportError: No module named Tutorial.settings

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy, importerror

I am using "scrapy" to scrape the author and quote from "quotes.to.scrape.com", I am passing the scraping requests through a pool of elite rotating proxy.
when the scraping is done without a proxy, the result is successful. When the proxy is used, it shows error - "ImportError: No module named Tutorial.settings".

I trigger the scraper within the proxy code by using 'call' function

I am a beginner python coder. Thanks in advance!

Following is my code :

```
proxies = ['hardcoded proxies']  
proxy_pool = cycle(proxies) 
url = 'httpbin.org/ip'; 

for i in range(1,12): #Get a proxy from the pool
    proxy = next(proxy_pool) 
    print("Request #%d"%i) 
try: 
    response = requests.get(url,
    proxies={"http": proxy, "https": proxy}) 
    print(response.json()) 
    print("ping/handshake passed through proxy") 
    call(["scrapy","crawl","extract_text_author","extract.jl"])
    #terminal equivalent command of triggering scrapy crawler

    print("scrapy passed through proxy") 

except: 
    print("Skipping. Connnection error")
```

Comment: Please edit the code into your question, don't post it as a comment, as it can't be nicely formatted.

Comment: apologies, code included in the question.